# java txt file reading program that only reads the first line of a txt file

Tags: java

I wrote a program that reads the number of times the letters a,e,s, and t and spaces occur in a txt file, and it currently works, but only reads the first line of the txt file.  How do I make my program read all of the lines in a txt file, and then output the number of times these letters are used?  Thank you for your time and help.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Count
    {
      public static void main (String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException {

      String phrase;  // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;          // an individual character in the string
      int countA;
      int countE;
      int countS;
      int countT;

      java.io.File file = new java.io.File("counting.txt");
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     phrase = inFile.nextLine();
     length = phrase.length();

          // Initialize counts

      while (true)
      { 
      if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))

          break;

      else
      {

      countBlank = 0;
      countA = 0;
      countE = 0;
      countS = 0;
      countT = 0;

      for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )   
       { 
       if ( phrase.charAt( i ) == ' ' )

        countBlank++;
        ch = phrase.charAt(i);

           switch (ch)
            {
             case 'a':
             case 'A':  countA++;
                     break;
         case 'e':
         case 'E':  countE++;
             break;
         case 's':
         case 'S':  countS++;
                break;
         case 't':
         case 'T':  countT++;
            break;
          }

     }
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
            System.out.println ();

        System.out.println ("Number of A's: " + countA);
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Number of E's: " + countE);
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Number of S's: " + countS);
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Number of T's: " + countT);
        break;

      }     
     }


     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looping over the file with a `while-loop`.

Replace `phrase = inFile.nextLine();` with:

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) // While there are lines in the file
    phrase += inFile.nextLine(); // Add line to 'phrase'
```

Don't forget to initialize `String phrase` with an empty string:

```
String phrase = "";
```

**Edit:** Your final code should look like this, with some changes, listed at the end of this answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    String phrase = ""; // a string of characters
    int countBlank; // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
    int length; // the length of the phrase
    char ch; // an individual character in the string
    int countA;
    int countE;
    int countS;
    int countT;

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("sample.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        phrase += inFile.nextLine(); // Add line to 'phrase'
    length = phrase.length();

    // Initialize counts

    while (true) {

        countBlank = 0;
        countA = 0;
        countE = 0;
        countS = 0;
        countT = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ch = phrase.charAt(i);

            switch (ch)
            {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                countA++;
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                countE++;
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                countS++;
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                countT++;
                break;
            case ' ':
                countBlank++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Number of A's: " + countA);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of E's: " + countE);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of S's: " + countS);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of T's: " + countT);
        break;

    }

}
```

**Changes:**

- Deleted `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` since you don't use it.
- Added the code I suggested above
- Deleted `if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) break;`
- Added `switch-case` when `ch == ' '`
- Added `default-case` since it is considered good programming practice.

Comment: I made these changes to the program and it still returns the same thing.

Comment: txt file or java file?

Comment: The brown cow jumped over the moon.
Humpty Dumpty had a great fall.
The Packers have won 4 Super Bowls.
Go Timberwolves!

Comment: except after each period is a new line

Comment: Could you give me the expected result for that input? Or maybe you can give me a smaller example iwth its respective result.

Comment: a-6, e-11 , s-2 , t-6, 18 blank spaces.  I think it may only be reading the first 2 lines in the txt file

Answer (score 0):

Of course, You should use `while` in order the wrap `inFile.nextLine()` to produce you lines. But since you only use it once it only producing you the first line.

Try wrapping you code with this:

```
while ((phrase = inFile.nextLine()) != null) {
    // Here code
}
```

Comment: I did that and now the program returns 0s for all of the letters.  Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the next line to String "phrase". 
Add

> phrase = inFile.nextLine();

to the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Line

```
phrase = inFile.nextLine();
```

is out of your while loop. Hence it's getting executed only once. add it inside your while loop